# Titanium Scrollable view is jerky, momentarily stops half way

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I have been trying to figure out why a scrollable view in my app is very jerky, it momentarily stops half way when I swip between pages. The contents of each page is not complex, just a few text fields and an image. The number of pages is up to 8.
The versions I use are; Titanium 3.1.2GA Alloy 1.2.1 iOS 6.1.3 on an iPhone4 <<< Important - the jerkyness is not that visible on the iPhone5
Please note that I started this project in November last year and have along the way upgraded my enviroment when new releases have become available. Could there be some old code being used? I saw an early pre-1.0 Alloy bug raised for this issue, could it still be there in my environment?
I created a test app using the standard two tab Alloy template and added the code below. For the second tab I had just saved to the disk the image used in tab 1. Tab 3 did not have any images but was still a bit jerky. In my app I have a few more views on each page and it is very jerky.
If anyone have any suggestions I would really appreciate it. It would be great if someone please confirm the issue with an iPhone4, just to have make sure my environment is not the cause (I guess i could try to uninstall and reinstall but I am not sure how to properly uninstall everything).
Cheers, Lars

Index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup>
        <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
            <Window id="window1" title="Tab 1">
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab title="Tab 2" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window id="window2" title="Tab 2">
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab title="Tab 3" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
            <Window id="window3" title="Tab 3">
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
```

Index.js

```
function createViews() {
    var v10 = createPage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg', "#00FFFF");
    var v11 = createPage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg', "#FF00FF");
    var v12 = createPage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg', "#FFFF00");
    var v13 = createPage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg', "#FFFFFF");
    var v14 = createPage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg', "#FFFFFF");
    var v15 = createPage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg', "#FFFFFF");

    var v20 = createPage("images/Mona_Lisa.jpg", "#00FFFF");
    var v21 = createPage("images/Mona_Lisa.jpg", "#FF00FF");
    var v22 = createPage("images/Mona_Lisa.jpg", "#FFFF00");
    var v23 = createPage("images/Mona_Lisa.jpg", "#FFFFFF");
    var v24 = createPage("images/Mona_Lisa.jpg", "#FFFFFF");
    var v25 = createPage("images/Mona_Lisa.jpg", "#FFFFFF");

    var v30 = createPage(null, "#229900");
    var v31 = createPage(null, "#333333");
    var v32 = createPage(null, "#009900");
    var v33 = createPage(null, "#FF77FF");
    var v34 = createPage(null, "#007744");
    var v35 = createPage(null, "#009988");
    var v36 = createPage(null, "#DDBB00");
    var v37 = createPage(null, "#CCCCCC");
    var v38 = createPage(null, "#99FFFF");

    var photosView1 = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
        views:[
            v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15 // http images
        ],
        showPagingControl:true,
        cacheSize: 21
    });

    $.window1.add(photosView1);

    var photosView2 = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
        views:[
            v20,v21,v22,v23,v24,v25 // file images
        ],
        showPagingControl:true,
        cacheSize: 21
    });
    $.window2.add(photosView2);

    var photosView3 = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
        views:[
            v30,v31,v32,v33,v34,v35  // colored pages
        ],
        showPagingControl:true,
        cacheSize: 21
    });
    $.window3.add(photosView3);
}

function createPage(image, bkgColor) {
    var detailsView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: Ti.UI.FILL,
        top: 5,
        left: 5,
        right: 5,
        bottom: 100,
        backgroundColor: bkgColor
    });

    if (image) {
        var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:image
        });
        detailsView.add(imageView);
    }

    var labelView0 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: "Label 0"
    });
    detailsView.add(labelView0);

    var pageView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: Ti.UI.FILL,
        backgroundColor: "#E4E8E8"  
    });
    pageView.add(detailsView);

    var labelContainer = Ti.UI.createView({
        height: 90,
        bottom: 5,
        left: 5,
        right: 5,
        backgroundColor: "#FFAAFF"
    });
    pageView.add(labelContainer);

    var labelView1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        bottom: 50,
        text: "Label 1"
    });
    labelContainer.add(labelView1);

    var labelView2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        bottom: 10,
        text: "Label 2"
    });
    labelContainer.add(labelView2);

    return pageView;
}

createViews();
$.index.open();
```

6 Sep 2013 ...

Based on a comment that ambiguity of the layouts could cause the jerkyness I have now tried with views that have absolute positions and sizes. I also used just images from the file system that had the exact size as the image view. Please see code below. It is better but the jerkyness is still there which means that the underlaying issue is not resolved by absolute positions and sizes.

```
function createPage(image, bkgColor) {
    var detailsView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        top: 0,
        backgroundColor: bkgColor
    });

    if (image) {
        var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            image:image
        });
        detailsView.add(imageView);
    }
    else {
        var labelView0 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            text: "No Image"
        });
        detailsView.add(labelView0);
    }

    var pageView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        backgroundColor: "#E4E8E8"  
    });
    pageView.add(detailsView);

    var labelContainer = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        top: 300,
        backgroundColor: "#FFAAFF"
    });
    pageView.add(labelContainer);

    var labelView1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        width: 300,
        height: 20,
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
        text: "Label 1"
    });
    labelContainer.add(labelView1);

    var labelView2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        width: 300,
        height: 20,
        top: 40,
        left: 10,
        text: "Label 2"
    });
    labelContainer.add(labelView2);

    return pageView;
}
```

Comment: Is it jerky in the iPhone 4 simulator?

Comment: No - in the simulator it works fine, probably due to a way better processor on my Mac than on the iPhone4.

Comment: Sometimes this happens if there is ambiguity in the layout attributes, for instance you have width, and height set to Ti.UI.FILL, and top left and right set, choose one or the other.

Comment: I do have width, and height set to Ti.UI.FILL, and top, bottom, left and right set on my detailsView to get an 'panel' visual look - I'll try to change that and see what happens. On that note, maybe the actual pageView should not have the width as FILL, I'll try setting a fixed width to be the width of the scrollable.

Comment: I have now tried this code in the KitchenSink example application where I just replaced the example views with the ones created by my code. The result was the same, still jerky. This means that Alloy is not a factor.

Comment: I changed the views to have absolute positions and sizes to eliminate the ambiguity factor - still jerky (but less jerky).

Comment: By using the debug options in the iPhone simulator I found that the image I used was misaligned, I changed the image and it is now better.

Comment: Also the debug options in the iPhone simulator I found that the Titanium Labels show up as Blended Layers, even though I set the backgroundColor and explicitly set the opacity to 1. I am hoping that someone here can shed some light why Labels are like that and how I can fix this issue.

Comment: I was going to raise a defect about the jerkyness with Appcelerator but a defect was already raised a few days earlier. Please see https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-15095. Hopefully it will be fixed soon as my app is not nice to use on an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it had to do with the `scrollableView.cacheSize` property. Try setting it to the length of your views array.

Comment: I had set the cacheSize to 21, a number larger than the max number of pages what I would expect to have in the scrollable. I tried your suggestion to have the cache set to exact the number of page but it did not change anything - thats for the suggestion though.

Comment: This solved a similar issue I were having for a long time. Really helpful :)